# Validation errors required Angular (frontend) and ASP.NET (backend)

Tags: asp.net, angular, validation

I am trying to create a new instance of a model from Angular with an ASP.NET backend. However I am facing validation errors saying that the fields are required.

This is what I have tried - template :

```
<h1>Add employee : </h1>

<form [formGroup]="form">
<label for="EmployeeName">Employee Name : </label>
<input type="text" formControlName="EmployeeName">

<label for="Department">Employee Department: </label>
<input type="text" formControlName="Department">

<label for="DateOfJoining">Date of joining : </label>
<input type="date" formControlName="DateOfJoining">

<label for="fileimage">Main image</label>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" fomrControlName="fileimage" (change)="onImageUpload($event)">

<button (click)="onSubmit()">Create Employee</button>
</form>
```

This is the Angular component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form=this.formBuilder.group({
      EmployeeName:[''],
      Department:[''],
      DateOfJoining:[''],
      fileimage:['', Validators.required]
    })
}

onImageUpload(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      this.form.patchValue({fileimage:file});
      this.form.get('fileimage').updateValueAndValidity();
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = ()=> {
        this.imageDisplay=fileReader.result;
      };

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const Employee : Employee = {
      EmployeeName:this.form.get('EmployeeName').value,
      Department:this.form.get('Department').value,
    };

    this.imageService.createEmployee(Employee, this.form.get('fileimage').value).subscribe(
      ()=>{
        console.log("Employee Created")
      },
      ()=>{
        console.log("Error in Employee Creation")
      }
    );
  }
```

This is the service I am working with :

```
createEmployee(employee:Employee, file:File):Observable<ArrayBuffer>{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;boundary=<calculated when request is sent>');

    const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=<calculated when request is sent>'
        }),
        body: {}
    }

    return this.http.post<ArrayBuffer>(`${this.apiURLEmployee}`, {employee, file}, options)
  }
```

And finally this is my backend endpoint :

```
public IActionResult Post([FromForm]Employee emp, IFormFile file)
{
    MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(_configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon"));

    int LastEmployeeId = dbClient.GetDatabase("BDD").GetCollection<Employee>("Employee").AsQueryable().Count();

    emp.EmployeeId = LastEmployeeId + 1;

    string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

    if (file != null)
    {
        string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var uploads = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, @"images\employee");
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        Uri domain = new Uri(Request.GetDisplayUrl());

        if (emp.PhotoFileName != null)
        {
            var oldImagePath = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, emp.PhotoFileName.TrimStart('/'));
                    
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(oldImagePath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(oldImagePath);
            }
        }

        using (var fileStreams = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, filename + extension), FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.CopyTo(fileStreams);
        }

        emp.PhotoFileName = domain.Scheme + "://" + domain.Host + (domain.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + domain.Port) + "/images/employee/" + filename + extension;
    }

    dbClient.GetDatabase("BDD").GetCollection<Employee>("Employee").InsertOne(emp);

    return Json("Employee added successfully");
}
```

The validation errors are from the backend. Here is the error :

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCzhb.jpg)

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1fH8.jpg)

[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKjqF.jpg)

Comment: Where are the validation errors? In the front end or back? Also please post the actual error.

Comment: Yes sure, I have posted the image error and the errors come from the backend not frontend

Comment: Can you please add the payload that is being sent to the backend?

Comment: What's the payload ?

Comment: The data that is being sent to the backend. You can find it in the browser Dev tools > network tab > Request

Comment: @Zze I've added the request to the post

Comment: No - we need the payload for that request. I want to see the object that is being sent to the backend.

Comment: I've added the request payload @Zze